# EF 4.1 Fluent Mapping Problem with One-to-One Relation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I can't map the follow Database structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJmIq.png

I want a Logo (LogoID is a UniqueKey) for one Media. Follow my fluent mapping:

```
public class SponsorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Sponsor>
{
    public SponsorMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);
        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.SiteAddress)
            .HasMaxLength(300);
        this.Property(t => t.TwitterName)
            .HasMaxLength(20);
        this.Property(t => t.FacebookAddress)
            .HasMaxLength(300);
        // Relationships
        //this.HasOptional(t => t.Logo);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Logo)
            .WithOptionalDependent();
    }
}
```

Follow Models:

```
   public class Sponsor{
    public Sponsor(){this.Goods = new List<Goods>();} public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SiteAddress { get; set; }
    public string TwitterName { get; set; }
    public string FacebookAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Goods> Goods { get; set; }
    public virtual Media Logo { get; set; }
}
    public class Media{
    public Media(){}
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Goods Good { get; set; }
    public virtual MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
}
```

I get follow error in my test:

```
Test method 

Inove.Kenquer.Data.Tests.UserRepositoryTest.When_Save_User_With_Action_Get_Same_Actions_From_DB threw exception: 
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Invalid column name 'Logo_ID'.**
-----------------------------------------
MediaMap has no mapping to Sponsor.
```

How can I map it?

Comment: Entity framework doesn't support unique keys so you cannot map one-to-one relation over unique key. The only way is to cheat it with one-to-many relation as @Eranga described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map it like this.

```
public SponsorMap()
{

    //other mappings

    HasOptional(sponsor => sponsor.Logo)
           .WithMany()
           .Map(sponsor => sponsor.MapKey("LogoID"));

    HasMany(sponsor => sponsor.Goods)
           .WithOptional(good => good.Sponsor)
           .Map(x => x.MapKey("SponsorID"));
}
```

**Edit:**

You need to map all navigational properties. I have added mapping between `Sponsor` and `Good` based on info you provided.

Go through some articles(eg : [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/)) on how to use fluent mappings.

You can use [EF power tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) to generate mapping for you.

Comment: Hi, Eranga, this dont works for me, follow exception: System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Sponsor_ID'.

Comment: @Thiago can you post your model classes. You have not configured some other property(similar to the one I gave in the answer)